# Paypal Payment Integration not returning any values

Tags: php

This is my code in PHP for paypal payment integration.Payments are being done successfully. The response URL should be http://codaty.com/success.php?tx=83437E384950D&st=Completed&amt=10.00&cc=USD&cm=&item_number=1 .But I am getting the URL as http://codaty.com/success.php. I am not getting any parameters in return. Is this the right method for integration. Can I get a sample code for reference.

```
$paypal_url='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
$paypal_id='codaty@outlook.com';
 <form action="<?php echo $paypal_url; ?>" method="post" name="frmPayPal1">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $paypal_id; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="QR Code">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="credits" value="510">
    <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?=$session_userid?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0.10">
    <input type="hidden" name="cpp_header_image" value="http://codaty.com/images/logo.png">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="handling" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://codaty.com/cancel.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://codaty.com/success.php">
    <input type="image" src="images/card03.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" class="img-responsive">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add addition `Return method` `input` hidden field `<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">`

`1` — the buyer's browser is redirected to the return URL by using the GET method, but no payment variables are included.

`2` — the buyer's browser is redirected to the return URL by using the POST method, and all payment variables are included.

And then in `success.php` :

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
```

More details : [HTML Variables for PayPal Payments Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/)

Comment: also you can add `<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://codaty.com/success.php">` value same as `http://codaty.com/success.php` and try this. let me know